# building dynamic XSLT in XQuery - using HTML passed into parameter

Tags: xslt-2.0, xquery-3.0

In XQuery 3.1 I am dynamically creating an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet to transform a `tei-xml` document into HTML.

In XQuery, I create a variable `$docdate` to store an HTML span:

```
<span><a href="somefoosite.com">2018-12-10</a></span>
```

Then I pass this to a parameter in the XSLT stylesheet, which then gets used:

```
let $stylesheet := 
           <xsl:stylesheet>
              [....]
              <xsl:param name="paramDocdate" as="element()*">{$docdate}</xsl:param>
              [....]
              <xsl:apply-templates select="$paramDocdate" mode="date"/>
              [....]
           </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm not sure in the `xsl:apply-templates` how to get the HTML to render as HTML, instead of just outputting the text `2018-12-10`. To be clear: the HTML elements are definitely coming through the parameter, not just the `text()`.

Alternately I imagine one can somehow serialize the HTML into a string when creating the variable in XQuery (to pass as a long string into the parameter)?

But I can't figure out how to do either of these things.

I'd rather avoid manually writing the HTML as a string directly while creating `$docdate` ...if it's possible to do this programatically.

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: It turns out this template below outputs the HTML from the parameter, but I'd be interested in hearing other ways to solve this...

```
 <xsl:template match="span" mode="date">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you have an element with the right name and namespace (e.g. either `span` with no namespace for HTML 4 or HTML5 or `span` with the XHTML namespace for XHTML) and just want to copy it through to the output you don't need `apply-templates` at all, you can simply use `<xsl:copy-of select="$paramDocdate"/>` directly.

But if you use `apply-templates` then obviously you need to ensure there is a template doing the right job (i.e. copying) you need, so either, as you have found, set up a template for `span` in the wanted mode that copies or set up a generic template like the identity transformation for that mode (or all modes with `xsl:template mode="#all"`) that performs the copy.